# plsql stored procedure taking parameter gives error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

I tried to create a procedure in pl/sql developer like,

```
create or replace procedure insert_muh_fis(birim_id in number(15)) is   
begin
     insert into muh_Fis_d013
     select * from muh_fis mf where mf.fk_birim_id = birim_id;
     --delete from muh_fis mf where mf.fk_birim_id = birim_id;
     --commit;
end;
```

But it gives me Compilation error.

```
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: := . ) , @ % öndeğer karakterThe symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
Line: 1
```

I would appreciate any idea to help me out solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the datatype precision in `IN` parameter, your parameter declaration should be like `birim_id IN NUMBER`.

Try,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE insert_muh_fis(birim_id IN NUMBER) 
IS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO muh_fis_d013
     SELECT * FROM muh_fis mf WHERE mf.fk_birim_id = birim_id;
     --delete from muh_fis mf where mf.fk_birim_id = birim_id;
     --commit;
END;
```